# Sending large images time to the GPU

Tags: image-processing, optimization, lua, gpu, torch

I am using a CNN model (AlexNet) implemented in Lua using Torch for image processing. I am modifying the [Torch starter code](https://github.com/cvondrick/torch-starter).

My problem is that I am making images with 18 channels instead of 3 channels for training the model, and for sending those images to GPU, it takes around 20 (2.13 s for every batch) times more than when it sends images with three channels (0.14s for every batch). I also tried to see how long it took to send images with 4 channels to GPU. I saw that as soon as the number of channels increased to more than 3 channels, the time increased about 20 times. For example, even for images with 4 channels, it took around 2s for every batch, which is around 19 times more than running 3 channel images.

I was wondering if there is a bug which makes it take this much time and if there aren't any bugs, if there is any way I can decrease this running time?

Comment: What are you modifying in the starter code to increase the channels?

Comment: I am finding the difference of seven frames in a video and then stack them , in this case instead of having images with 3 channels I have images with 18 channels as input to the CNN. I have modified the "donkey_simple.lua " where it gets the images and gets the differences of frames in a video and stacked them, and the first layer of CNN instead of 3, changed it to 18 channels and some tensor sizes in the code. This part "input:copy(data_im:squeeze())"  of "main.lua" takes a lot of time. And I found out that it is not the problem of squeezing.

Comment: have you tried to decrease the batch size to send the batch containing the same number of bytes to the gpu?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried the way you suggested. It takes the same time as before.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

This is a problem that isn't going away.  This is a bandwidth issue of CPU to GPU buffering.  You've increased the amount of data having to be sent across the bus by a large factor.

## Possible Workaround

The essence of what you are trying to do is to include previous frames in your model.  If that is what you want to accomplish there is another way of doing that.

If a training batch wasn't a random selection of stacked images, if instead a training batch was regular images but all sequential in time.

In the second case you would send in images with just 3 channels but the images would not be out of order.

Let's explore that what-if.

First, you could still create random sampling by changing the start time and end time for each batch and randomly pick which video to choose from.

Secondly, you could use the [batch,height,weight,channel] tensor to generate on the GPU a new tensor that is

```
[ batch[1:], height, width, channel] - [ batch[:-1], height, width, channel]
and assign it to diffTensor
```

and then concatenate the following tensors

```
origTensor [ batch[5:-0], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[5:-0], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[4:-1], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[3:-2], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[2:-3], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[1:-4], height, width, channel] 
diffTensor [ batch[0:-5], height, width, channel]
```

If you wanted 5 "look backs"

What would this accomplish?  Well, if you sent 100 images to the GPU, then this network would be able to generate 95 image+diff images for the network price of sending only 100 images where as if instead you tried to send 95 image+diff images that had 5 layers each you'd have to pay the network price of sending 500 images.  Basicly you can cut your network costs by *almost* **x5**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I did the way you suggested but the problem is still there, so I think sending images with 6 channels to the AlexNet may take a lot of time.